# I have added HTML code using append, but this new code do not execute javascript anymore

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

After inserting a code using Ajax , this code does not run the javascript it should be querying as it is identical to the code that had already been written in the page

I am trying to load a page, and update the database using Ajax (working).
I have a button that adds a new row to the page (working), in order to add more data to the table
Problem is that the new "appended" code does not execute the ajax as the written code does!

this code has been written while I loaded the page 
<td contenteditable="true" id="comments:99" class="html5">&nbsp;1q33</td>

this is the new code that I added using .append
<td contenteditable="true" id="comments:103" class="html5">&nbsp;2</td>

this is the javascript that is triggered on the initial code but it is not working for the .appended one 
$(':input[class=html5]').change(function () { });

I expected that the almost identical code that I wrote using .append worked similarly to the code I wrote while loading the page.

Comment: this is the javascript that is triggered on the initial code but it is not working for the .appended one
$(':input[class=html5]').change(function () {

                    });

Comment: I have no idea how it was working for the first ones to start with, because the shared code shows `td` elements and you query `:input` for the change handler..

Answer (score 1):

You can use as below::

```
$(':input[class=html5]').on("change", function () { });
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the three parameter version of the `on`  method, it will also apply to HTML that is added later to the document

```
$(document).on('change', ':input[class=html5]', function () { 
    //...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to refer a parent element that exists when you load the page for first time for trigger envents on your dynamically added elements

```
$('body').on('change', ':input[class=html5]', function() {

});
```